# Tricky conditional imputation, ideally using Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, aggregation, imputation

I have an issue where I need to do some tricky conditional imputation for missing values while flagging those imputed values, but I can't quite figure out how to approach it.

My data is in Tidy (long) format. What I want to do is produce a complete dataset where each "state" has a complete set of rows with "Births" values for "Male", "Female", and "Total". If "Total" is missing for a state, it is imputed from "Male" + "Female" for that "state". If we have "Total", but not either "Male" or "Female", the missing "Births" value is calculated from "Total" - "Male" (or "Female", depending on what is the missing one).

HOWEVER, the missing values can only be imputed if the "source" is the same for all of the present rows for that state. **We cannot impute based on combining data from different sources.** Finally, all imputed rows should have their parent state and source and should have a "1" flag for the binary "aggregated" column.

The reprex is below and the desired outcome example is below that with a quick explanation. I'd like to do this with Tidyverse if possible, but I am open to better solutions. Thank you in advance!!

```
sex <- c("Male", "Female", "Total", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Total") 
state <- c("New Jersey", "New Jersey", "New Jersey", "Vermont", "Vermont", "Washington", "Washington", "Montana", "Montana")
source <- c("WHO", "WHO", "WHO", "CDC", "CDC", "UN", "CDC", "UN", "UN")
aggregated <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
births <- c(20, 30, 50, 15, 16, 20, 27, 15, 33)

df <- data.frame(sex, state, source, aggregated, births)
df
     sex      state source aggregated births
1   Male New Jersey    WHO          0     20
2 Female New Jersey    WHO          0     30
3  Total New Jersey    WHO          0     50
4   Male    Vermont    CDC          0     15
5 Female    Vermont    CDC          0     16
6   Male Washington     UN          0     20
7 Female Washington    CDC          0     27
8   Male    Montana     UN          0     15
9  Total    Montana     UN          0     33
```

**Explanation of the produced set**

New Jersey: Complete from the start, no changes

Vermont: Missing Total, all sources identical (CDC), new row for Total created with Births imputed from Male + Female

Washington: Missing Total, but Male and Female have different sources, so nothing can be imputed

Montana: Missing Female, all sources identical (UN), new row for Female created with Births imputed from Total - Male.

```
      sex      state source aggregated births
1    Male New Jersey    WHO          0     20
2  Female New Jersey    WHO          0     30
3   Total New Jersey    WHO          0     50
4    Male    Vermont    CDC          0     15
5  Female    Vermont    CDC          0     16
6   Total    Vermont    CDC          1     31
7    Male Washington     UN          0     20
8  Female Washington    CDC          0     27
9    Male    Montana     UN          0     15
10 Female    Montana     UN          1     18
11  Total    Montana     UN          0     33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated 03**
Now I can rest in piece!

I know this is nothing compared to those 2 fabulous solutions proposed by dear @akrun . But I could not leave a solution here that did not lead to the desired output. So I made some modifications and here is the result, beside I extended the code in case `Male` value in `births` column is missing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = births) %>%
  pivot_longer(Male:Total, names_to = "sex", values_to = "births") %>%
  group_split(state, source) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ if(sum(is.na(.x$births)) > 1 ) drop_na(.x) else .x) %>%
  group_by(state, source) %>%
  mutate(aggregated = ifelse(is.na(births), 1, 0),
         births = ifelse(sex == "Female" & is.na(births), births[sex == "Total"] - 
                           births[sex == "Male"], 
                         ifelse(sex == "Total" & is.na(births), 
                                births[sex == "Female"] + births[sex == "Male"], 
                                ifelse(sex == "Male" & is.na(births), 
                                       births[sex == "Total"] - births[sex == "Female"], 
                                       births)))) %>%
  relocate(state, source, sex)


# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   state, source [5]
   state      source sex    aggregated births
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Montana    UN     Male            0     15
 2 Montana    UN     Female          1     18
 3 Montana    UN     Total           0     33
 4 New Jersey WHO    Male            0     20
 5 New Jersey WHO    Female          0     30
 6 New Jersey WHO    Total           0     50
 7 Vermont    CDC    Male            0     15
 8 Vermont    CDC    Female          0     16
 9 Vermont    CDC    Total           1     31
10 Washington CDC    Female          0     27
11 Washington UN     Male            0     20
```

**Updated**

The problem of `aggregated` column solved thanks to a fabulous solution from my dear teacher / friend @akrun :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>% 
  group_split(state, source) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ if(all(c('Male', 'Female') %in% .x$sex) && !'Total' %in% .x$sex)  
    { add_row(.x, sex = 'Total', state = first(.x$state), source = first(.x$source), aggregated = 1, births = sum(.x$births)) } 
          else if(all(c('Male', 'Total') %in% .x$sex) && !'Female' %in% .x$sex) 
            { add_row(.x, sex = 'Female', state = first(.x$state), source = first(.x$source), aggregated = 1, births = sum(.x$births)) } 
    else .x)


# A tibble: 11 x 5
   sex    state      source aggregated births
   <chr>  <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Male   Montana    UN              0     15
 2 Total  Montana    UN              0     33
 3 Female Montana    UN              1     48
 4 Male   New Jersey WHO             0     20
 5 Female New Jersey WHO             0     30
 6 Total  New Jersey WHO             0     50
 7 Male   Vermont    CDC             0     15
 8 Female Vermont    CDC             0     16
 9 Total  Vermont    CDC             1     31
10 Female Washington CDC             0     27
11 Male   Washington UN              0     20
```

**Updated 02**

Yet another great solution by dear @akrun:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(state, source) %>% 
  complete(sex = unique(df$sex)) %>% 
  arrange(state, source, factor(sex, levels = c('Male', 'Female', 'Total'))) %>% 
  filter(sum(is.na(aggregated)) > 1 & !is.na(aggregated)|sum(is.na(aggregated)) <= 1) %>% 
  mutate(aggregated = replace(aggregated, is.na(aggregated), 1), 
         births = case_when(is.na(births) &  row_number() == n() ~ sum(births, na.rm = TRUE), 
                            is.na(births) ~ last(births) - na.omit(births)[1], TRUE ~ births))

# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   state, source [5]
   state      source sex    aggregated births
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Montana    UN     Male            0     15
 2 Montana    UN     Female          1     18
 3 Montana    UN     Total           0     33
 4 New Jersey WHO    Male            0     20
 5 New Jersey WHO    Female          0     30
 6 New Jersey WHO    Total           0     50
 7 Vermont    CDC    Male            0     15
 8 Vermont    CDC    Female          0     16
 9 Vermont    CDC    Total           1     31
10 Washington CDC    Female          0     27
11 Washington UN     Male            0     20
```

Comment: It says that if in a give group Total/ Female is missing and we calculate it, the corresponding aggregated value should be 1. In Vermont we calculate the Total value by adding a row and in Montana we have Total and we calculate the Female so their respective values in aggregated turned to 1.

Comment: You can do `df %>% group_split(state, source) %>% map_dfr(~ if(all(c('Male', 'Female') %in% .x$sex) && !'Total' %in% .x$sex)  {  add_row(.x, sex = 'Total', state = first(.x$state), source = first(.x$source), aggregated = 1, births = sum(.x$births))} else .x)`

Comment: I realized that for Montana one more row needs to be added, you can specify an `else if` condition for that

Comment: Thank you very much. `add_row` seems like an interesting solution.

Comment: Or you could use `adorn_totals` with a condition

Comment: When we add a new row by `add_row` function, do we have to define all column values?

Comment: otherwise, it will be NA  which you can later `fill` with the previous non-NA

Comment: I thought in order to add a new row we have to pivot first and add it as a column and then pivot back. But this is so much easier. Thank you very much.

Comment: @akrun It worked like an absolute charm! But I'm not gonna post it in my name. Please post it here:
`df %>% 
  group_split(state, source) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ if(all(c('Male', 'Female') %in% .x$sex) && !'Total' %in% .x$sex)  {  add_row(.x, sex = 'Total', state = first(.x$state), source = first(.x$source), aggregated = 1, births = sum(.x$births))} 
          else if(all(c('Male', 'Total') %in% .x$sex) && !'Female' %in% .x$sex) 
            { add_row(.x, sex = "Female", state = first(.x$state), source = first(.x$source), aggregated = 1, births = sum(.x$births))} else .x)`

Comment: It is okay.  You could mention my name

Comment: I think this may also work `df %>% group_by(state, source) %>% complete(sex = unique(df$sex)) %>% arrange(state, source, factor(sex, levels = c('Male', 'Female', 'Total'))) %>% filter(sum(is.na(aggregated)) > 1 & !is.na(aggregated)|sum(is.na(aggregated)) <= 1) %>% mutate(aggregated = replace(aggregated, is.na(aggregated), 1), births = case_when(is.na(births) &  row_number() == n() ~ sum(births, na.rm = TRUE), is.na(births) ~ last(births) - na.omit(births)[1], TRUE ~ births))`

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you @Anoushiravan R and @akrun! Very much appreciated. Answer marked as accepted.

Comment: @woggles Oh your welcome you should be thanking him. I did nothing, still figuring out a way of completing my solution.

Comment: @akrun I'm terribly sorry to bother you. Would you please just tell me what this doesn't work, I spent two hours to no avail: It says `Error: Argument 1 must have names.`
`df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = births) %>%
  pivot_longer(Male:Total, names_to = "sex", values_to = "births") %>%
  group_split(state, source) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ ifelse(sum(is.na(.x$births)) > 1, drop_na(.x), .x))`

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I would use `if/else` as `ifelse` requires all the arguments to be same length and also similar structure, but in this case, it would be different i.e. you are returning data.frame/tibble.  `df %>%   pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = births) %>% pivot_longer(Male:Total, names_to = "sex", values_to = "births") %>% group_split(state, source) %>% map_dfr(~ if(sum(is.na(.x$births)) > 1) drop_na(.x) else .x)`

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much, I saw you used it in your first solution, thought I could try a different one.